# java script expand div and bg image based on window size

Tags: javascript, css, html

Well sorry, first question. I am kind of learning all this by trial and error. Anyhow I cannot figure out how to duplicate this 1 script.

What i am trying to do is use javascript or somthing to expand a div and bg image inside that div based on the size of the window. For an example of what i am trying to do please check out [42floors](http://42floors.com).

My project is formated

```
/* header */

/* I want to expand dynamically */
<div>

/*Content area with title showing at bottom like example site, even when window is expanded. */
<div>

/* footer */
```

Any insight or direction would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at their source code. They are using the following:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(your-image.png);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind that `background-size` is not supported in IE6-8.

Comment: Already tried that and it is not duplicating the effect. It has to be some sort of java script. In the example, the div class=hero has a height style inline that auto changes with browser size and the div below that with class=cta-container has padding-top that changes as well. I believe this is what creates the image resize effect with changing the size of the browser and keeps that div with "the best place to find office space" secured in that bottom area when browser size is adjusted... Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/ for full support, like above, background-size is an option if you don't give a **** about IE < 9

Answer (score 0):

a fairly simple programmatic approach would be to add an event listener to the window resize event and calculate the height/width and appropriate resize the image/div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        //change the size of your div using something like
        $(div).css("width", value);
        $(div).css("height", value);
    });
});
```

this uses Jquery by the way. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js